# UI is not showing server data in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am a novice in angular 2 and started learning the concepts. I have a component which is not showing data when bound with my controller. The Ui gets loaded with hard coded data though.
Here is my Component
personal-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { PersonalDetails } from '../Shared/personal-details.type';
import { PersonalDetailsService } from '../services/personal-details.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'personal-details',
    templateUrl: './personal-details.component.html'
})
export class PersonalDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() DetailsObtained: PersonalDetails;
    constructor(private personalDetailsService: PersonalDetailsService) {
        //this.DetailsObtained = {            
        //    Address : "from client",
        //    ContactNumber : "1112225436",
        //    EmailAddress:"client@gmail.com-client",
        //    Name : "sandeep"
        //}
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.personalDetailsService.getPersonalDetails().
            then(details => {
                this.DetailsObtained = details
            });

    }
}
Service
personal-details.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {PersonalDetails} from '../Shared/personal-details.type';

@Injectable()

export class PersonalDetailsService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }
    getPersonalDetails() {
        var personalDetails = this.http.get('api/PersonalDetails/GetPersonalDetails')
            .map(response => response.json() as PersonalDetails).toPromise();
        return this.http.get('api/PersonalDetails/GetPersonalDetails')
            .map(response => response.json() as PersonalDetails).toPromise();
    }
}
```

Controller:
PersonalDetailsController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Skills.Entities;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace Skills.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")] // api/PersonalDetails
    public class PersonalDetailsController : Controller
    {
        private static PersonalDetailsEntities _personalDetailsEntities = new PersonalDetailsEntities()
        {
            Name = "Sandeep Dutta- server",
            Address = "from  server",
            EmailAddress = "server@gmail.com",
            ContactNumber ="1112224356"
        };
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult GetPersonalDetails()
        {
            return new ObjectResult(_personalDetailsEntities);
        }
    }
}
```

On debugging I found that it is asking for Name property which is already a part of the response. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Below mentioned is the stack trace from chrome debugger

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PersonalDetailsComponent.html:12)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:24216)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23363)
>       at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23723)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23655)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23364)
>       at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23723)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23681)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23359)
>       at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=RCvRrqPvM2Kc5BlkEQ045FeXR6gPMRIwfn51ludN14I:sourcemap:23723)

Personal-details.component.html

```
 <div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Some basic personal information!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <p>Full Name:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ DetailsObtained?.Name  }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <p>Address:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ DetailsObtained?.Address   }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <p>EmailAddress:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ DetailsObtained?.EmailAddress }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <p>ContactNumber:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ DetailsObtained?.ContactNumber | formatPhoneNumber }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in your html (PersonalDetailsComponent.html:12)

```
{{DetailsObtained?.name}}
```

'?' - said that DetailsObtained can be undefined (it undefined while u w8 for data from server)

and u will not have this mistake.

Better use resolvers for component and get all data from your server before rendering your component

Comment: Hi Александр Петрик : Thanks for your response. I tried {{DetailsObtained?.name}} but that is not working. Can you please elaborate a little on how to use resolvers for components?

Comment: this link on safe navigation operator (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths). Can u add your html to question and output of your details variable?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I have added the html as well in the question for your reference. After adding the Angular safe navigation operator (?.) the I am not seeing the null reference error any more but it is giving me 500 Internal Server error. Looks like something wrong in my service.

Comment: So its not angular problem now

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
So after certain efforts I could figure out the following:

1. In order to get the json output displayed on the UI using angular/typescript, the result has to be in a form of collection. this.entity = result will not work. Instead this.entityCollection = result as json() would work
2. The Internal Server error was because of the wrong format of result set only. After correcting the format of the result set, I am able to see the data on the UI

Thanks all